# How do we create select (combo) box in android

Tags: android, select, combobox, android-widget

I want integrate one combo filled with currency types. please tell me any way to create select box in android. i have created spinner but i have similar different views to show on page. and it is not looking attractive. please share any code for select.

Comment: It's better if you show your "unattractive" page. Also, what do you mean by "select box"?

Answer (score 2):

use this dynamic_spinner_main.java

```
package example.sampleLocalization;

import java.util.ArrayList;

//import com.matthias.dynamicSpinnerT.R;
//import com.matthias.dynamicSpinnerT.R.id;
//import com.matthias.dynamicSpinnerT.R.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class dynamic_spinner_main extends Activity {

    private Spinner m_myDynamicSpinner;
    private EditText m_addItemText;
    private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> m_adapterForSpinner;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_spinner);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //grab our UI elements so we can manipulate them (in the case of the Spinner)
        //    or add listeners to them (in the case of the buttons)
        m_myDynamicSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.dynamicSpinner);        
        m_addItemText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newSpinnerItemText);
        Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.AddBtn);
        Button clearButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ClearBtn);

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //create an arrayAdapter an assign it to the spinner
        m_adapterForSpinner = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        m_adapterForSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);        
        m_myDynamicSpinner.setAdapter(m_adapterForSpinner);
        m_adapterForSpinner.add("gr");        

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //add listener for addButton
        addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {               
                addNewSpinnerItem();
            }                   
        });

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //add listener for addButton
        clearButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clearSpinnerItems();
            }           
        });  
    }

    private void addNewSpinnerItem() {
        CharSequence textHolder = "" + m_addItemText.getText();
        m_adapterForSpinner.add(textHolder);
    }

    private void clearSpinnerItems() {
        m_adapterForSpinner.clear();
        m_adapterForSpinner.add("dummy item");
    }       
}
```

Comment: your method is good,but the spinner not also update,the new add data not show in the spinner,only update m_adapterForSpinner? how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

main_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:id="@+id/newSpinnerItemText" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></EditText>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/AddBtn" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Add To Spinner"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/ClearBtn" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:text="Clear Spinner Items"></Button>
    <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/dynamicSpinner" 
            android:layout_margin="4px" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"></Spinner>
</LinearLayout>
```